# Android can't run simple onTextChange code

Tags: android, android-edittext

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText addressTextBox;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addressTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        addressTextBox.addTextChangedListener(addressWatcher);
    }

    private final TextWatcher addressWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            addressTextBox.setText("dsa");
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    };
}
```

When I change the text it shows that my application isn't responding wait/close.

1. Why does this happen and how can I fix that?
2. What does `s` stand for in the `onTextChanged` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be wrong about this, but it seems like:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        addressTextBox.setText("dsa");
    }
```

Would constantly trigger itself.  Meaning that the text changed, ran this function, which changes the text, which runs this function, and so on forever.

Comment: S is charSequence of  EditText

Answer (score 0):

GO to your logcat and find the stack trace, it will tell you what happened.  Probably the problem is because you set the text in onTextChanged.  I don't think that's allowed (I think you can only change it in afterTextChanged), and even if it is it would cause infinite recursion (as the change would call the watcher again).

As for what s is-  s is the text in the edit field.  Read the  [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)